# yeoman webapp scaffold live reload working but not refreshing css

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, livereload

New to npm, bower, grunt and all. I got yeoman working with the webapp generator and live reload works fine for html pages. My scss file compiles to a .tmp folder and the changes work as they should but I have to manually press f5 or refresh in order to see the css changes.

If I save the corresponding html file, the css gets updated. When I save the .scss file, I have to manually update it. Javascript also doesn't get updated on save of a js file but updates when I save index.html.

I am on ubuntu 14. Here is part of my grunt file.

```
  watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
  babel: {
    files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['babel:dist']
  },
  babelTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['babel:test', 'test:watch']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  sass: {
    files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['sass:server', 'postcss']
  },
  styles: {
    files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'postcss']
  }
},

browserSync: {
  options: {
    notify: false,
    background: true
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      files: [
        '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*',
        '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      port: 9000,
      server: {
        baseDir: ['.tmp', config.app],
        routes: {
          '/bower_components': './bower_components'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      port: 9001,
      open: false,
      logLevel: 'silent',
      host: 'localhost',
      server: {
        baseDir: ['.tmp', './test', config.app],
        routes: {
          '/bower_components': './bower_components'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      background: false,
      server: '<%= config.dist %>'
    }
  }
},
```

I'm new to all this but have spent all day trying to solve this and am burnt out. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you